# why permission denied in ubuntu htdocs folder?

Tags: ubuntu

I set my htdocs permission like this

```
chmod 766 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

but i can not create any folder normaly in htdocs folder it says permission denied.

what is the solution ???

Comment: try in root mode ..

Comment: yes root mode is ok, but i want it in normal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that htdocs folder NOT be open to "others" with the flag of 777.  If you really want access to it in a SAFE way, do the following:

1. Look at the group the htdocs folder currently belongs to (probably `root`).
2. Create a group (or use an existing group) to which both root, yourself, and any applications that require access to htdocs can join (hint look at `useradd` or `usermod`).
3. Set the permissions on the htdocs folder to 770 or 77? where `? = whatever permission you want to give to all other users that are not the owner and not in the group.

Setting to 777 means to:

- First 7 = give full/uncontrolled access to the owner
- Second 7 = give full/uncontrolled access to everyone in the group
- Third 7 = give full/uncontrolled access to everyone else (potentially dangerous)

Comment: Thanks @Justin Carroll

Comment: @kousheralampranto, your welcome.  While both your answer and my answer solved the problem, if you found that my answer could be helpful to others in the future and is more appropriate/proper for a linux solution, if you could mark it as "Accepted" (green check-mark) it would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

after set the mode to 777 the problem has gone.

Comment: we can give answer to our own question .. :o